# negative margin not working in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```
 <style>
            .earthlogo{float: right; margin: -270px 0px 0px 0px;}
 </style>

    <div class="banner">   
        <p>ENVISIONING A BETTER TOMORROW</p> 
        <div class="earthlogo">
            <img src="images/earth.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here I applied the negative margin to class `earthlogo` and its working in firefox and google chrome but not in IE 7. So is this a correct way to apply negative margin in CSS and if it is correct way then why its not working in IE 7. How can I fix IE issue.

Thanks

Comment: don't used to negative margin in ie7 used to position:relative; top:-270px;

Comment: Personaly I recommend avoiding margins if you want IE compatibility, and try use padding instead. (Just general tip.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of negative `margins`, you can use `position: relative;` along with negative `top` or `left` offsets;

```
.earthlogo {
     position: relative;
     top: -270px; /*pull it 270 pixels up*/
     left: 0px; /*we don't want to pull it to the left*/
     margin: 0px; /*make sure no margins are applied*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
position: relative;
```

along with

```
 top:270px left:0px offsets
```